# Record not deleted from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code to show MySQL records on a web site table.
This is the column whith the delete button:

```
<td align="center"><a id="<?php echo $row['id_peticion']; ?>" class="delete-link" href="#" title="Delete">
            <img src="delete.png" width="20px" />
            </a></td>
```

This is the JS code called when user clicks on the delete button:

```
/* Data Delete Starts Here */
    $(".delete-link").click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var del_id = id;
        var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
        if(confirm('Seguro que quieres borrar la petición # = ' +del_id))
        {
            $.post('delete.php', {'del_id':del_id}, function(data)
            {
                parent.fadeOut('slow');
            }); 
        }
        return false;
    });
    /* Data Delete Ends Here */
```

And this is the code from delete.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($_POST['id_peticion'])
{
    $id = $_POST['id_peticion'];    
    $stmt=$db_con->prepare("DELETE FROM tbpeticiones WHERE id_peticion=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));  
}
?>
```

When clicked, the record dissapears from the table but is not deleted from the database.

I cannot find the reason why...
Thank you

Comment: Check from browser->network if correct information is sent to "delete.php".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for `$_POST['id_peticion']` while the delete id is gonna be in `$_POST['del_id']`. Change your code to :

```
if($_POST['del_id'])
{
    $id = $_POST['del_id'];    
    $stmt=$db_con->prepare("DELETE FROM tbpeticiones WHERE id_peticion=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your post key is `del_id` not `id_peticion` as specified in the jquery:

```
$.post('delete.php', {'del_id':del_id}, function(data)
```

Comment: nice catch. Didn't notice.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes i'm super careful to keep variable names identical though ajax process, to easy to mess up